# SendKeys numeric output was wrong when keyboard language changed

Tags: c#, sendkeys

**INTRO**

I have create a project that read unique id from smart card with smart card reader. I extract `HEX` value from smart card id and convert to `DECIMAL`. After that I use `SendKeys.SendWait()` for putting result to another Web Application in registration process.

**PROBLEM**

Everything work fine until keyboards language was changed to others, the result came out as non numeric character.

**C# PROBLEM CODE**

```
SendKeys.SendWait('123456789');
```

What is a normal practice to prevent sending numeric character problem??

Comment: Posting a snippet that contains a single line of code that cannot compile is not going to get you an answer.  SendKeys is a horrid hack from the 1990s, the only reason it got added to the .NET Framework was to allow VB programmers to port their code.  Use a decent UI Automation library instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Is there any UI Automation library you would recommend to me then?

Comment: @HansPassant actually, the rest of code is not relevant to this question. so, I decide not to include it